# Converting ByteBuffer to String and vice vera - change in structure of ByteBuffer

Tags: java, string

I was trying to convert a ByteBuffer to String and vice versa. 
Manually, I debugged my code to get the state of the byteBuffer before converting it to a string and after as well:

So my HashMap where I store the ByteBuffer looks something like this:

```
0 = {HashMap$Node@10653} "studentId" -> "{S: ER3478CT2016,}"
1 = {HashMap$Node@10693} "collegeId" -> "{S: 123456,}"
2 = {HashMap$Node@10694} "changeField1" -> "{B: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=424 cap=424],}"
3 = {HashMap$Node@10696} "studentAddress" -> "{B: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=64 cap=64],}"
4 = {HashMap$Node@10697} "studentName" -> "{B: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32 cap=32],}"
5 = {HashMap$Node@10699} "studentTerm" -> "{B: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32 cap=32],}"
```

But once I convert it to a String and back to a ByteBuffer, I see the following change:

```
0 = {HashMap$Node@10653} "studentId" -> "{S: ER3478CT2016,}"
1 = {HashMap$Node@10693} "collegeId" -> "{S: 123456,}"
2 = {HashMap$Node@10694} "changeField1" -> "{B: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=422 cap=466],}"
3 = {HashMap$Node@10696} "studentAddress" -> "{B: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=121 cap=121],}"
4 = {HashMap$Node@10697} "studentName" -> "{B: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=56 cap=72],}"
5 = {HashMap$Node@10699} "studentTerm" -> "{B: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=42 cap=78],}"
```

The way I convert my ByteBuffer to a String is:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = map.get("changeField1");
String myValue = new String(buffer.array(), "UTF-8");
```

Also, the way I convert the string back to a byteBuffer looks like this:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = CharSet.forName("UTF-8").encode(myValue);
```

Why is there a change in the limits and cap values when the string is converted back to a byteBuffer? I was thinking since I don't know the ByteBuffer's encoding and I use UTF-8 to encode it to a String, that might the reason? Is that correct or is there a more efficient way to convert byteBuffers to Strings and vice versa?

Comment: Is `String myValue = new String(changeField.array(), "UTF-8");` actually suppose to be `String myValue = new String(buffer.array(), "UTF-8");`? Could you edit?

Comment: If you convert it back to string again, which strings do you have in the beginning and in the end?

Comment: @lexicore: The strings are fine. I am not modifying the strings anywhere. I am storing the strings as such. Are you telling me to convert the obtained byteBuffer again to a string and see what's the result?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of the implementation for the `Charset.encode()` method

```
int n = (int)(in.remaining() * averageBytesPerChar());
ByteBuffer out = ByteBuffer.allocate(n);
```

As you can see, the capacity of the buffer is not a one-to-one correspondence to the input `in`, rather based on another factor returned by `averageBytesPerChar()`, hence the size of the buffer is slightly bigger. Here is the complete implementation of `Charset.encode()`

```
    public final ByteBuffer encode(CharBuffer in) throws CharacterCodingException
    {
        int n = (int)(in.remaining() * averageBytesPerChar());
        ByteBuffer out = ByteBuffer.allocate(n);

        if ((n == 0) && (in.remaining() == 0))
            return out;
        reset();
        for (;;) {
            CoderResult cr = in.hasRemaining() ?
                encode(in, out, true) : CoderResult.UNDERFLOW;
            if (cr.isUnderflow())
                cr = flush(out);

            if (cr.isUnderflow())
                break;
            if (cr.isOverflow()) {
                n = 2*n + 1;    // Ensure progress; n might be 0!
                ByteBuffer o = ByteBuffer.allocate(n);
                out.flip();
                o.put(out);
                out = o;
                continue;
            }
            cr.throwException();
        }
        out.flip();
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I am a bit confused. Is this an actual answer to change my approach? Or is this to tell me the place where I am going wrong?

Comment: The difference you are getting is due to the implementation of the method which was what I was trying to get across

Answer (score 0):

The suspicion I have is that `ByteBuffer.array()` actually gives you the whole byte array which backs the buffer - not just the filled part. `ByteBuffer.array()` does not consider `limit`. So your string may contain other characters constructed from bytes of the backing byte array.

Comment: After you mentioned this - I modified the code to look something like this:
ByteBuffer buffer = map.get("changeField1");
byte[] ba = new byte[buffer.limit()];
buffer.get(ba);
String myValue = new String(ba, "UTF-8");

Still the same error/change in limits.

Comment: @chrisrhyno2003 So what's different in buffers? Bytewise?

Comment: Ah nothing really. Bytewise was the only argument I could come up with. But otherwise it doesn't really make a huge difference I suppose.